# PHP Include statement full URL

Tags: php, include

I have a html template which has to be included in many php files deployed on multiple servers. For ex : 
The path of my html file is http://example.com/test.html on server 1 .
I have test1.php, test2.php deployed on server 2 & 3 respectively. I am using the statement http://example.com/test.html'); ?>, I am getting an error saying

http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0.

I tried changing it but nothing works. Any work around for this? Or any other way where I could achieve this functionality?

P.S : For some reason my PHP include statement wont show in my question. I have added the statement in the comment section.

Comment: <?php include('http://example.com/test.html'); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it should work, be sure that these two settings are correct in your php.ini:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
```

(restart the http server)

If it's a shared host and you can't change main php.ini, you probably need to create a .**htaccess** in your "www" or "public_html" folder with this content:

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

Or you can try to create a custom php.ini inside your home folder(if your server allows it).

Answer (score 0):

Try [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)  or curl.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `include` with URL you have to enable [`allow_url_include`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) from php.ini

Set

```
allow_url_include = 1
```

Or

in code

```
ini_set('allow_url_include','1')
```